# Coding Issue with Java game

Tags: java

I'm writing some code for a text based game for my Computer Science class, but I'm having some problems with this code
[(java code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5sJh.png).

The all the code works until I put in the if/else statements, so I want to know where I should be putting the statements at.

[(Error Message)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bu116.png)

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.ArrayList;

class Progress {

public String udc;
public String u = "up";
public String d = "down";

public void start() {
System.out.println("Hello.");
}


public void c1() {
Scanner name=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("What's your name?");
System.out.println("Hello "+name.nextLine()+".");
} 

public void uod() {
Scanner ud = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Up or down?");
udc = ud.nextLine();
}

public void uodc() {
System.out.println("going "+udc+".");
}

public void end() {
System.out.println("Press any key to exit");
}
}


public class APGame {
public static void main(String[] args) {

Progress p =new Progress();
p.start();
p.c1();
p.uod();
if (u.equals(udc)) {p.uodc();}
else {p.oud();}
p.end();
}}
```

Comment: from the looks of the screenshot, the code is not a lot. so, please edit your post with the code appended.

Comment: We need the actual code to be pasted in here. As an image we cannot manipulate or change the code.

Comment: Please edit your question and put in your source code in a well-formatted manor. And give the exact error message.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should include the lines of code in the question. It will be easier for us to copy paste in our IDE and test.

Comment: And your actual problem is...?

Comment: Please add the code here in your question.

Answer (score 1):

`u` and `udc` variables are defined inside another class, that is `Progress`, and should be accessed (as they are public), by `p.u` and `p.udc`.

```
if (p.u.equals(p.udc)) ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

`udc` and `u` are instance variables of the class `Progress`. So the problem with the if-else statement is that you are not referencing `udc` from any object of the Progress class. To fix it do:

```
if(p.u.equals(p.udc) {
  p.uodc();
}else{
  p.uod();
}
```